# Sending UDP message using ESP32

Tags: c++, udp, esp32, send, arduino-ide

This is my first time with wireless networking so I'm sure I'm doing something dumb, but I have been banging my head against the wall during 2 weeks and can't seem to get this up and running.

I'm trying to send a message from my ESP32 to my server any time it wakes up. It should be easy, but i'm completely frustrated. For testing in my house, I'm using UDP Monitor app on my phone, this app aparently let you receive and send UDP messages, but after trying all my best i cant recive any message on my phone. I'm also using wireshark to look if the packet is getting send properly but the packet didn't appear on wireshark. I've try to use as udpAdress 255.255.255.255 and the udpAdress with the IP of the device I want to send to. I've try to send different types of packet. I've try to use different ports. I've try to use different libraries and i've try all the tutorials i've seen on internet and nothing happens. So It would be amazing if anyone can help with this.

This is the last code i try :

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#define BUTTON_PIN_BITMASK 0x200002000

const char* ssid = "*****";
const char* password = "*****";

/*const char* ssid = "*****";
const char* password = "*****";*/

WiFiUDP udp;
const char * udpAddress = "255.255.255.255";
const int udpPort = 3333;

int MY_PIN = 13;
int MY_PIN2 = 33;
int MY_PIN3 = 15;

RTC_DATA_ATTR int bootCount = 0;


void setup(){
    Serial.begin(115200);
    ++bootCount;
    Serial.println("Boot number: " + String(bootCount));

    pinMode(MY_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(MY_PIN2, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(MY_PIN3, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(MY_PIN3, HIGH);

    Serial.println("Booting");
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("Connected to wifi");

    Serial.println("Ready");
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    
    udp.begin(udpPort);
    Serial.println(udp.remotePort());
    Serial.println(udp.remoteIP());
    uint8_t message[50] = "hello world";
    udp.beginPacket(udpAddress, udpPort);
    udp.write(message,11);
    udp.endPacket();
    Serial.println("UDP send to: ");
    Serial.println(udp.remoteIP());
    Serial.println(udp.remotePort());
    Serial.println("          ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    delay(500);

    int reading = digitalRead(MY_PIN);
    int reading2 = digitalRead(MY_PIN2);

    if(reading == 1 ||reading2 == 1) {
        esp_sleep_enable_ext1_wakeup(BUTTON_PIN_BITMASK,ESP_EXT1_WAKEUP_ALL_LOW);;
    }
    else {
        esp_sleep_enable_ext1_wakeup(BUTTON_PIN_BITMASK,ESP_EXT1_WAKEUP_ANY_HIGH);;
    }

    Serial.println("Going to sleep now");

    esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_PERIPH,   ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
    esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_SLOW_MEM, ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
    esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_RTC_FAST_MEM, ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
    esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_XTAL,         ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
    esp_sleep_pd_config(ESP_PD_DOMAIN_MAX,          ESP_PD_OPTION_OFF);
    esp_deep_sleep_start();

    Serial.println("check_sleep");
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("check_sleep2");
}
```

The UDP part was extracted from a tutorial and a little bit modified. I've also try to use udp.printf or udp.broadcastto sentences and i can't even send the packet. Why isn't working? What am I missing? Any orientation is welcomed. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: `255.255.255.255` is not a valid host IP. You need the IP of the device you want to send to.

Comment: i've also try with the IP of the device and doesnt work